# ImportError: Please install apex from https://www.github.com/nvidia/apex to use distributed and fp16 training

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch

cannot install apex for distributed and fp16 training of bert model
i have tried to install by cloning the apex from github and tried to install packages using pip

i have tried to install apex by cloning from git hub using following command:

git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex.git

and cd apex to goto apex directory and tried to install package using following pip command:

pip install -v --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext"

full code is:

```
def main(server_ip,server_port,local_rank,no_cuda,fp16,train_batch_size,gradient_accumulation_steps,seed,do_train,do_eval,output_dir,task_name,data_dir,do_lower_case,bert_model,num_train_epochs,cache_dir,learning_rate,warmup_proportion,loss_scale,max_seq_length):
        if server_ip and server_port:
            # Distant debugging - see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_attach-to-a-local-script
            import ptvsd
            print("Waiting for debugger attach")
            ptvsd.enable_attach(address=(server_ip, server_port), redirect_output=True)
            ptvsd.wait_for_attach()

        processors = {"ner":NerProcessor}
        print(processors)

        if local_rank == -1 or no_cuda:
            device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() and not no_cuda else "cpu")
            n_gpu = torch.cuda.device_count()
        else:
            torch.cuda.set_device(local_rank)
            device = torch.device("cuda", local_rank)
            n_gpu = 1
            # Initializes the distributed backend which will take care of sychronizing nodes/GPUs
            torch.distributed.init_process_group(backend='nccl')
        logger.info("device: {} n_gpu: {}, distributed training: {}, 16-bits training: {}".format(
            device, n_gpu, bool(local_rank != -1), fp16))

        if gradient_accumulation_steps < 1:
            raise ValueError("Invalid gradient_accumulation_steps parameter: {}, should be >= 1".format(
                                args.gradient_accumulation_steps))

        train_batch_size = train_batch_size // gradient_accumulation_steps

        random.seed(seed)
        np.random.seed(seed)
        torch.manual_seed(seed)

        if not do_train and not do_eval:
            raise ValueError("At least one of `do_train` or `do_eval` must be True.")

        if os.path.exists(output_dir) and os.listdir(output_dir) and do_train:
            raise ValueError("Output directory ({}) already exists and is not empty.".format(output_dir))
        if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
            os.makedirs(output_dir)

        task_name = task_name.lower()

        if task_name not in processors:
            raise ValueError("Task not found: %s" % (task_name))

        processor = processors[task_name]()
        label_list = processor.get_labels()
        num_labels = len(label_list) + 1

        tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(bert_model, do_lower_case=do_lower_case)

        train_examples = None
        num_train_optimization_steps = None
        if do_train:
            train_examples = processor.get_train_examples(data_dir)
            num_train_optimization_steps = int(
                len(train_examples) / train_batch_size / gradient_accumulation_steps) * num_train_epochs
            if local_rank != -1:
                num_train_optimization_steps = num_train_optimization_steps // torch.distributed.get_world_size()

    #     # Prepare model
        cache_dir = cache_dir if cache_dir else os.path.join(str(PYTORCH_PRETRAINED_BERT_CACHE), 'distributed_{}'.format(local_rank))
        model = Ner.from_pretrained(bert_model,
                  cache_dir=cache_dir,
                  num_labels = num_labels)
        if fp16:
            model.half()
        # model.cuda()
        model.to(device)
        if local_rank != -1:
            try:
                from apex.parallel import DistributedDataParallel as DDP
            except ImportError:
                raise ImportError("Please install apex from https://www.github.com/nvidia/apex to use distributed and fp16 training.")

            model = DDP(model)
        elif n_gpu > 1:
            model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)

        param_optimizer = list(model.named_parameters())
        no_decay = ['bias', 'LayerNorm.bias', 'LayerNorm.weight']
        optimizer_grouped_parameters = [
            {'params': [p for n, p in param_optimizer if not any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)], 'weight_decay': 0.01},
            {'params': [p for n, p in param_optimizer if any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)], 'weight_decay': 0.0}
             ]
        if fp16:
            try:
                from apex.optimizers import FP16_Optimizer
                from apex.optimizers import FusedAdam
            except ImportError:
                raise ImportError("Please install apex from https://www.github.com/nvidia/apex to use distributed and fp16 training.")

            optimizer = FusedAdam(optimizer_grouped_parameters,
                                  lr=learning_rate,
                                  bias_correction=False,
                                  max_grad_norm=1.0)
            if loss_scale == 0:
                optimizer = FP16_Optimizer(optimizer, dynamic_loss_scale=True)
            else:
                optimizer = FP16_Optimizer(optimizer, static_loss_scale=loss_scale)

        else:
            optimizer = BertAdam(optimizer_grouped_parameters,
                                 lr=learning_rate,
                                 warmup=warmup_proportion,
                                 t_total=num_train_optimization_steps)

        global_step = 0
        nb_tr_steps = 0
        tr_loss = 0
        label_map = {i : label for i, label in enumerate(label_list,1)}
        if do_train:
            train_features = convert_examples_to_features(
                train_examples, label_list, max_seq_length, tokenizer)
            logger.info("***** Running training *****")
            logger.info("  Num examples = %d", len(train_examples))
            logger.info("  Batch size = %d", train_batch_size)
            logger.info("  Num steps = %d", num_train_optimization_steps)
            all_input_ids = torch.tensor([f.input_ids for f in train_features], dtype=torch.long)
            all_input_mask = torch.tensor([f.input_mask for f in train_features], dtype=torch.long)
            all_segment_ids = torch.tensor([f.segment_ids for f in train_features], dtype=torch.long)
            all_label_ids = torch.tensor([f.label_id for f in train_features], dtype=torch.long)
            all_valid_ids = torch.tensor([f.valid_ids for f in train_features], dtype=torch.long)
            all_lmask_ids = torch.tensor([f.label_mask for f in train_features], dtype=torch.long)
            train_data = TensorDataset(all_input_ids, all_input_mask, all_segment_ids, all_label_ids,all_valid_ids,all_lmask_ids)
            if local_rank == -1:
                train_sampler = RandomSampler(train_data)
            else:
                train_sampler = DistributedSampler(train_data)
            train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_data, sampler=train_sampler, batch_size=train_batch_size)

            model.train()
            for _ in trange(int(num_train_epochs), desc="Epoch"):
                tr_loss = 0
                nb_tr_examples, nb_tr_steps = 0, 0
                for step, batch in enumerate(tqdm(train_dataloader, desc="Iteration")):
                    batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
                    input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_ids, valid_ids,l_mask = batch
                    loss = model(input_ids, segment_ids, input_mask, label_ids,valid_ids,l_mask)
                    del loss
                    if n_gpu > 1:
                        loss = loss.mean() # mean() to average on multi-gpu.
                    if gradient_accumulation_steps > 1:
                        loss = loss / gradient_accumulation_steps

                    if fp16:
                        optimizer.backward(loss)
                    else:
                        loss.backward()

                    tr_loss += loss.item()
                    nb_tr_examples += input_ids.size(0)
                    nb_tr_steps += 1
                    if (step + 1) % gradient_accumulation_steps == 0:
                        if fp16:
                            # modify learning rate with special warm up BERT uses
                            # if args.fp16 is False, BertAdam is used that handles this automatically
                            lr_this_step = learning_rate * warmup_linear(global_step/num_train_optimization_steps, warmup_proportion)
                            for param_group in optimizer.param_groups:
                                param_group['lr'] = lr_this_step
                        optimizer.step()
                        optimizer.zero_grad()
                        global_step += 1
```

main('','',-1,True,True,8,1,42,True,True,'jpt','ner','data/',True,'bert-base-cased',5,'cache_dir',5e-5,0.4,0,128)

Comment: Why do you need that at all. Every model has a half precision?

Comment: for distributed and fp16 training

Comment: You can write [distributed apps in PyTorch as well](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/dist_tuto.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import os, sys, shutil
import time
import gc
from contextlib import contextmanager
from pathlib import Path
import random
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm, tqdm_notebook

@contextmanager
def timer(name):
    t0 = time.time()
    yield
    print(f'[{name}] done in {time.time() - t0:.0f} s')

USE_APEX = True

if USE_APEX:
            with timer('install Nvidia apex'):
                # Installing Nvidia Apex
                os.system('git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex; cd apex; pip install -v --no-cache-dir' + 
                          ' --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" ./')
                os.system('rm -rf apex/.git') # too many files, Kaggle fails
                from apex import amp
```

Comment: if you working  on colab  then https://stackoverflow.com/a/57903798/8927035